# Are all .NET framework versions included in new windows versions?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-2.0

I know that .NET Framework is not backward compatible (ex. Installing 4.0 dlls does not include 3.0 dlls)

But what about Windows installations? ex. Windows 7 includes .NET 3.5, what about 2.0 is it installed as well ?

Which Windows versions includes .NET 2.0 dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 3.5 does include .NET 2.0 DLLs. It is the same CLR. See here for an overview:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history) for the .NET Framework version history, you will see a table of the versions and which operating systems ship with it.

To summarize the wiki entry:

> 1.0 is part of Windows XP Tablet and Media Center Editions.
>
> 1.1 is part of Windows Server 2003
>
> 2.0 is part of Windows Server 2003 R2
>
> 3.0 is part of Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008. [Note: 3.0 and 3.5 are extensions of .NET 2.0; so 3.0 includes 2.0 and 3.5 includes 3.0 and 2.0]
>
> 3.5 is part of Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> 4.5 is part of Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012
>
> 4.6 is a part of Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016

So to answer your question, Windows Server 2003 R2, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2, Windows 7 all include the .NET Framework 2.0. That's because the 3.0 and 3.5 are all built on top of .NET 2.0; and cannot exist without it.